# data binding with two sets of multiple images simultaneously using Recycler view in android

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Our problem is to update multiple images in recycler view by clicking any single item[of recycler view] using data binding but initially we were able to update images only at some positions using databinding in ImageAdapter's xml.But according to our search in android developer site,we were suggested to use recycler view instead of our initial approach.[before clicking any image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGUnc.png)

[after clicking any image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EdSh.png)

The above approach is by using data binding in image adapter which is shown below.

Image Adapter

```
package tene.com.darxstudios;

import android.content.Context;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = ImageAdapter.class.getName() ;
    Context mContext;
    List<Integer> cropsList1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> cropsList2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    User user0 = new User(),user1 = new User(),user2 = new     User(),user3 = new User(),user4 = new User();
    public ImageAdapter(Context mContext,List<Integer>     cropsList1,List<Integer> cropsList2){
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.cropsList1 = cropsList1;
        this.cropsList2 = cropsList2;

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cropsList1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return cropsList1.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,     ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

//        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);

        final User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName(cropsList1.get(position));

        tene.com.darxstudios.ItemViewBinding binding =      DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
        binding.setUser(user);

        View view = binding.getRoot();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)     view.findViewById(R.id.image);


//        if(position == 0){
//            user0 = user;
//        }else if(position == 1){
//            user1 = user;
//        }else if(position == 2){
//            user2 = user;
//        }else if(position == 3){
//            user3 = user;
//        }else if(position == 4){
//            user4 = user;
//        }

         imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
              user.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(position));
//                user0.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(0));
//                user1.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(1));
//                user2.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(2));
//                user3.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(3));
//                user4.setFirstName(cropsList2.get(4));
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

item_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data class=".ItemViewBinding">
        <variable  name="user" type="tene.com.darxstudios.User"/>
    </data>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        firstName='@{user.firstName}'/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

We need to update all the images in a single click of any image using recycler view with data binding in android.

Answer (score 0):

Put your requisite logic for changing image inside a onClickListener inside the onBindViewHolder. Refer to recyclerview tutorial to understand how to implement it. The following code will deal with only the onClickListener.

```
public class NumReelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NumReelAdapter.recyclerViewHolder> {

List<NumReel> data = Collections.emptyList();
Context ctx;
int selectedPosition = 0;
```

The onBindViewHolder

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final recyclerViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final NumReel current = data.get(position);
    if(selectedPosition == position){
        // here highlighting the background. And set the inside color to green
        holder.itemView.setBackground(whatever_image_id);
    } else {
        //reset the color to white
        holder.itemView.setBackground(whatever_it_had_before);
    }
    holder.vItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //refresh the adapter
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            //change clicked position
            selectedPosition = position;
            //reset the adapter with new position highlighted
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            if (numClickListener != null) {
                String vTag = v.getTag().toString();
                //numClickListener.repsClick(v, position); alternate method where data can't be sent
                numClickListener.numClick(vTag, current.num);
            }
        }
    });
```

Here you can check any particular attribute of the clicked image and then make consequent changes. So in your case, you would have to check the name of the image. So if chick-peas is clicked then the background becomes a paddy field.